# Draw straight-line between two points in BlackBerry maps

Tags: blackberry, maps

How do I draw a straight-line between 2 points in BlackBerry maps? I've found how to draw a route between 2 points. I want draw a line like in the following picture, where 4 points are used.

[image]

Comment: On what platform and OS?

Comment: for platform blackberry OS 4.7